# My query to create an intersection (and) between two conditions doesn't work, why ? (Hibernate, Java, Rest Application)

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, intersection

```
@GET
@Path("/colors/{params: .*}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Espece> findByColors(@PathParam("params") List<PathSegment> params){
    CriteriaBuilder cb = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Espece> cq = cb.createQuery(Espece.class);
    Root<Espece> birdType = cq.from(Espece.class);
    Join<Espece, Couleur> couleurs = birdType.join(Espece_.colors);

    List<Predicate> restrictions = new ArrayList<>();
    for(PathSegment param : params){
        restrictions.add(cb.equal(cb.lower(couleurs.get(Couleur_.nom)), param.toString().toLowerCase()));
    }
    cq.where(cb.and(restrictions.toArray(new Predicate[]{})));
    /*cq.select(birdType)
        .where(restrictions.toArray(new Predicate[]{}));*/

    return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
}
```

There is my method to search a bird with one or multiple colors (A bird can have more than one color). And when I'm searching with only one color : *http://localhost:8084/NataRest/bird/colors/black* it works fine.
But when I'm searching with two colors : *http://localhost:8084/NataRest/bird/colors/black/yellow* it gives me an empty answer (And yes I have some birds in my database which are black and yellow).
I checked multiple forums and still not finding a way to make this work... I can make an union with a 'or' and 'distinct'. But not a intersection like I want :/

Thanks for advance for the help !
Okan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve my problem, I wrote the MySql Code to do what I wanted to do.
It opens my eyes on the fact I wanted that a = "yellow" and a = "black", so it's impossible.
There is the solution I built.
Create a list of queries (a query per color) and make a intersection between the results of these queries.

```
@GET
@Path("/colors/{params: .*}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Espece> findByColors(@PathParam("params") List<PathSegment> params){
    List<Query> queries = new ArrayList<>();
    for(PathSegment param : params){
        CriteriaBuilder cb = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Espece> cq = cb.createQuery(Espece.class);
        Root<Espece> birdType = cq.from(Espece.class);
        Join<Espece, Couleur> couleurs = birdType.join(Espece_.colors);
        cq.where(cb.equal(cb.lower(couleurs.get(Couleur_.nom)), param.getPath().toLowerCase()));
        queries.add(getEntityManager().createQuery(cq));
    }

    List<Espece> result = queries.get(0).getResultList();
    for(int i = 1; i < queries.size(); i++){
        result.retainAll(queries.get(i).getResultList());
    }

    return result;
}
```